# Recursive variable debug stack trace - Google Dialogflow API

Tags: python, google-api, dialogflow-es

I don't know if this issue is exclusive to Google's Dialogflow API or to other Google products or whether its specific to PyCharm's debugger.

I am using Python 2.7 trying to understand why there is no `sentiment_analysis_request_config` field in the [QueryResult()](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.QueryResult) object when the documentation says there is.

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'QueryResult' object has no attribute 'sentiment_analysis_result'
```

Whenever I debug my Dialogflow program, I get a recursive variable debug stack for a Google-specific object.

[image: Recursive variable]

Is this some sort of intended obfuscation on Google's end? Why can't I see the variables/methods associated with this Object/Type?

Edit: Image link did not work, here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9MjA.png

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DaImTo my question is not specifically about my error its rather about the behavior of the debugger. I simply added the error to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

It likely isn't obfuscation, and you *are* seeing the properties associated with this type. The "issue" is that one of those properties is a reference to the Descriptor, which is itself. There is nothing wrong with a circular reference, and it can be useful in some cases. It looks like you should be able to collapse the nested references and see the other properties.

Comment: [Image: No Properties](https://i.imgur.com/r80Q3fh.png) So I get that, but I also can't see any other properties. They are all empty when I try to expand them. This may be a limitation of PyCharm.